# Use of HTML5 custom data attribute for AJAX response

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, html

I have never used HTML5 much and so am not aware of its limitation.

But I have heard there is a useful custom data attribute which has got added. So my question is, can I use this for AJAX response handling? By that I mean, say I have coded some placeholder divs with data attributes.

Now can I parse this JSON response to fill up the div elements easily. Or is there another quicker way?

Main thing is HTML structure would be separate and json response will only contain data.

Comment: Could you clarify what your questions are? Would make it much easier for us to answer. Edit your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check out the [`jQuery.template()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.template/) plugin

Comment: Hey...thx a lot for that...jQurry template seems to be very helpful from what i have just read....But, there are a lot of things going through my mind and so am a bit confused as to what to use...My requirement is going to fill a div grid (can be 2-col or 3-col or in general any other kind)...Should i not consider using the html5 data element for this ? Also no need of DOJO? Please suggest.thx.

Comment: Also my response is going to come from a Java clas..so what kind of things to take care from the server side?